# Strauss model : no specular component

Tags: shaders, glsl, fragment-shader, webgl

I implemented the Strauss model with the metalness, transparency and smoothness parameters, taking the formulas from the book "Programming vertex geometry and pixel shaders", this is how I implemented it:

```
float fresnel(float x) {
    float Kf= 1.12;
    float result= 1.0/pow(x-Kf,2.0) - 1.0/(Kf*Kf);
    result/= 1.0/pow(1.0-Kf,2.0) - 1.0/(Kf*Kf);
    return result;
}

float shadow(float x) {
    float Ks= 1.01;
    float result= 1.0/pow(1.0-Ks,2.0) - 1.0/pow(x-Ks,2.0);
    result/= 1.0/pow(1.0-Ks,2.0) - 1.0/(Ks*Ks);
    return result;
}

vec4 Strauss(vec3 L, vec3 N, vec3 V, float smoothness, float metalness, float transparency) 
{
    vec3 H= reflect(L,N);
    float HdotV= max(dot(H,V),0.0);
    float NdotL= max(dot(N,L),0.0);
    float NdotV= max(dot(N,V),0.0);
    float k=0.1;

    // Diffuse component
    vec3 diffuse= NdotL * (1.0 - metalness * smoothness) * (1.0 - pow(smoothness,3.0)) * (1.0 - transparency) * vec3(materialDiffuse);

    // Specular component
    float r= (1.0-transparency) - (1.0 - pow(smoothness,3.0)) * (1.0 - transparency);
    float j= fresnel(NdotL) * shadow(NdotL) * shadow(NdotV);
    float reflect= min(1.0,r+j * (r+k));
    vec3 C1= vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    vec3 Cs= C1 + metalness * (1.0 - fresnel(NdotL)) * (vec3(materialSpecular) - C1);
    vec3 specular= pow(-HdotV, 3.0/(1.0-smoothness)) * reflect * Cs;

    return max(lightDiffuse * vec4(diffuse,1.0) ,0.0) + max(lightSpecular * vec4(specular,1.0), 0.0);
}
```

The parameters metalness, smoothness and transparency are uniforms. I try to vary them, but I cannot get something similar to this result:

[image]

This is what I get with roughness 0.9, transparency 0.1 and metalness 0.1 :

[image]

It is practically equal to a lambert shader! I tried a lot of parameters combination, but I never get a shiny teapot like it should be.
I also debugged the shader, and it seems like the specular component is zero in many parts of the teapot. I tried to add an if that makes look red all the areas where the specular component is zero, that's the result:

[image]

I checked many times the formulas and the implementation, and it seems like I've done all correctly. What's the problem?

Comment: I think you already asked this question, why not update the original question ?

Comment: @concept3d This is the Strauss model, the other question was on the Ward model. It's not a duplicate. Re-open it please.

Comment: I voted for re-open sorry. I can't open it. needs a moderator.

Comment: While this doesn't seem a duplicate after all, it's still exclusively about debugging your code for you...

Comment: I'd still consider it a duplicate because in theory one could ask the very same question about every concievable lighting model otherwise.

Comment: If there's an error it's in the formula implementation, which is different from the Ward model.